# Yahoo Messenger - How to mass-export entire message archive as text files

Tags: export, yahoo-messenger

I would like to export my entire message archive to plain text format so I can search it.  Is this doable?

Comment: good question...+1

Comment: Now at **version 10**, you would think Yahoo! Messenger would have native archive search functionality, *and* store the archive in text, xml, or some other readable format. Anyone know why not? Is there some business reason for this? ...cause it makes no technical or usability sense. (Oh, +1. Good question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yahoo! Messenger Archive Viewer](http://www.wackyb.co.nz/yahoo/archive_viewer/) can do this for you. Some features need to be paid for, but it exporting to plain text it does for free. It also allows you to search your archive.

Comment: +1. It's got an awkward, clunky interface, but gets the job done. Thanks.

Comment: @billweaver you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can find resembling what you are asking for is this utility: [Yahoo Message Archive Decoder](http://www.ikitek.com/products/Yahoo-Message-Archive-Decoder.html). It seems to work well, although some things like email addresses come up scrambled, and you have to pay to see them.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked up this PHP script to export my archives.  Bulk of the code is taken from two other scripts by clever people as noted in the comments.

Works with Yahoo Messenger up to version 10 where all the message archiving was done locally, but not with later versions.  I'm using Windows XP, to run the PHP script I simply installed [VertrigoServ](http://vertrigo.sourceforge.net/) and made this the index file for the web server, then open

```
http://localhost/
```

in my browser.

All matching files are outputted in order of modified time, oldest first.

Configure these parameters to suit:

```
// Where your Yahoo Messenger files are kept
 $archive_dir = 'C:/Program Files/Yahoo!/Messenger/Profiles';

 // Regular expression filtering the path names of file for particular
 // user names (e.g. I want all the messages I've exchanged with john or
 // bob
 $archive_people_files ='/Messages.*(john|bob)/'; 

 // Output file name
 $output_file_name = 'ym_output.txt';

 // Name of my account
 $from_name = 'geoffs_account_name';

 // My name as I want it to appear in the output
 $to_name = 'geoff';
```

The full script:

```
<?php
// Put together using these scripts:
// http://www.pgregg.com/projects/php/preg_find/preg_find.php.txt
// http://www.0xcafefeed.com/2007/12/yahoo-messenger-archive-file-format/

// Found on http://superuser.com/questions/130196/yahoo-messenger-how-to-mass-export-entire-message-archive-as-text-files

 /**
 * Usage:
 * ./decodeYahoo.php account contact file
 *
 * 'account' is the Y!M account name.
 * 'recipient' is the name of the contact
 * 'file' is the file to parse.
 *
 * Please note: There is no error checking
 * in the code below. If you want to use
 * this code for anything important, please
 * add some. Also, fopen/fread would be more
 * memory efficient than a file_get_contents,
 * but again, I'm being super lazy today. (o:
  */


date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

// Where your Yahoo Messenger files are kept
$archive_dir = 'C:/Program Files/Yahoo!/Messenger/Profiles';

// Regular expression filtering the path names of file for particular user names (e.g. I want all the messages I've exchanged with john or bob
$archive_people_files ='/Messages.*(john|bob)/'; 

// Output file name
$output_file_name = 'ym_output.txt';

// Name of my account
$from_name = 'geoffs_account_name';

// My name as I want it to appear in the output
$to_name = 'geoff';

$entry_name="";
$rg_files=array();

/*
 * Find files in a directory matching a pattern
 *
 *
 * Paul Gregg <pgregg@pgregg.com>
 * 20 March 2004,  Updated 20 April 2004
 * Updated 18 April 2007 to add the ability to sort the result set
 * Updated 9 June 2007 to prevent multiple calls to sort during recursion
 * Updated 12 June 2009 to allow for sorting by extension and prevent following
 * symlinks by default
 * Version: 2.3
 * This function is backwards capatible with any code written for a
 * previous version of preg_find()
 *
 * Open Source Code:   If you use this code on your site for public
 * access (i.e. on the Internet) then you must attribute the author and
 * source web site: http://www.pgregg.com/projects/php/preg_find/preg_find.phps
 * Working examples: http://www.pgregg.com/projects/php/preg_find/
 *
 */

define('PREG_FIND_RECURSIVE', 1);
define('PREG_FIND_DIRMATCH', 2);
define('PREG_FIND_FULLPATH', 4);
define('PREG_FIND_NEGATE', 8);
define('PREG_FIND_DIRONLY', 16);
define('PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC', 32);
define('PREG_FIND_SORTDESC', 64);
define('PREG_FIND_SORTKEYS', 128); 
define('PREG_FIND_SORTBASENAME', 256);   # requires PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC
define('PREG_FIND_SORTMODIFIED', 512);   # requires PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC
define('PREG_FIND_SORTFILESIZE', 1024);  # requires PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC
define('PREG_FIND_SORTDISKUSAGE', 2048); # requires PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC
define('PREG_FIND_SORTEXTENSION', 4096); # requires PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC
define('PREG_FIND_FOLLOWSYMLINKS', 8192);

// PREG_FIND_RECURSIVE   - go into subdirectorys looking for more files
// PREG_FIND_DIRMATCH    - return directorys that match the pattern also
// PREG_FIND_DIRONLY     - return only directorys that match the pattern (no files)
// PREG_FIND_FULLPATH    - search for the pattern in the full path (dir+file)
// PREG_FIND_NEGATE      - return files that don't match the pattern
// PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC - Instead of just returning a plain array of matches,
//                         return an associative array with file stats
// PREG_FIND_FOLLOWSYMLINKS - Recursive searches (from v2.3) will no longer
//                            traverse symlinks to directories, unless you
//                            specify this flag. This is to prevent nasty
//                            endless loops.
//
// You can also request to have the results sorted based on various criteria
// By default if any sorting is done, it will be sorted in ascending order.
// You can reverse this via use of:
// PREG_FIND_SORTDESC    - Reverse order of sort
// PREG_FILE_SORTKEYS    - Sort on the keyvalues or non-assoc array results
// The following sorts *require* PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC to be used as they are
// sorting on values stored in the constructed associative array
// PREG_FIND_SORTBASENAME - Sort the results in alphabetical order on filename
// PREG_FIND_SORTMODIFIED - Sort the results in last modified timestamp order
// PREG_FIND_SORTFILESIZE  - Sort the results based on filesize
// PREG_FILE_SORTDISKUSAGE - Sort based on the amount of disk space taken
// PREG_FIND_SORTEXTENSION - Sort based on the filename extension
// to use more than one simply seperate them with a | character



// Search for files matching $pattern in $start_dir.
// if args contains PREG_FIND_RECURSIVE then do a recursive search
// return value is an associative array, the key of which is the path/file
// and the value is the stat of the file.
Function preg_find($pattern, $start_dir='.', $args=NULL) {

  static $depth = -1;
  ++$depth;

  $files_matched = array();

  $fh = opendir($start_dir);

  while (($file = readdir($fh)) !== false) {
    if (strcmp($file, '.')==0 || strcmp($file, '..')==0) continue;
    $filepath = $start_dir . '/' . $file;
    if (preg_match($pattern,
                   ($args & PREG_FIND_FULLPATH) ? $filepath : $file)) {
      $doadd =    is_file($filepath)
               || (is_dir($filepath) && ($args & PREG_FIND_DIRMATCH))
               || (is_dir($filepath) && ($args & PREG_FIND_DIRONLY));
      if ($args & PREG_FIND_DIRONLY && $doadd && !is_dir($filepath)) $doadd = false;
      if ($args & PREG_FIND_NEGATE) $doadd = !$doadd;
      if ($doadd) {
        if ($args & PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC) { // return more than just the filenames
          $fileres = array();
          if (function_exists('stat')) {
            $fileres['stat'] = stat($filepath);
            $fileres['du'] = $fileres['stat']['blocks'] * 512;
          }
          if (function_exists('fileowner')) $fileres['uid'] = fileowner($filepath);
          if (function_exists('filegroup')) $fileres['gid'] = filegroup($filepath);
          if (function_exists('filetype')) $fileres['filetype'] = filetype($filepath);
          if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) $fileres['mimetype'] = mime_content_type($filepath);
          if (function_exists('dirname')) $fileres['dirname'] = dirname($filepath);
          if (function_exists('basename')) $fileres['basename'] = basename($filepath);
          if (($i=strrpos($fileres['basename'], '.'))!==false) $fileres['ext'] = substr($fileres['basename'], $i+1); else $fileres['ext'] = '';
          if (isset($fileres['uid']) && function_exists('posix_getpwuid')) $fileres['owner'] = posix_getpwuid ($fileres['uid']);
          $files_matched[$filepath] = $fileres;
        } else
          array_push($files_matched, $filepath);
      }
    }
    if ( is_dir($filepath) && ($args & PREG_FIND_RECURSIVE) ) {
      if (!is_link($filepath) || ($args & PREG_FIND_FOLLOWSYMLINKS))
        $files_matched = array_merge($files_matched,
                                   preg_find($pattern, $filepath, $args));
    }
  }

  closedir($fh); 

  // Before returning check if we need to sort the results.
  if (($depth==0) && ($args & (PREG_FIND_SORTKEYS|PREG_FIND_SORTBASENAME|PREG_FIND_SORTMODIFIED|PREG_FIND_SORTFILESIZE|PREG_FIND_SORTDISKUSAGE)) ) {
    $order = ($args & PREG_FIND_SORTDESC) ? 1 : -1;
    $sortby = '';
    if ($args & PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC) {
      if ($args & PREG_FIND_SORTMODIFIED)  $sortby = "['stat']['mtime']";
      if ($args & PREG_FIND_SORTBASENAME)  $sortby = "['basename']";
      if ($args & PREG_FIND_SORTFILESIZE)  $sortby = "['stat']['size']";
      if ($args & PREG_FIND_SORTDISKUSAGE) $sortby = "['du']";
      if ($args & PREG_FIND_SORTEXTENSION) $sortby = "['ext']";
    }
    $filesort = create_function('$a,$b', "\$a1=\$a$sortby;\$b1=\$b$sortby; if (\$a1==\$b1) return 0; else return (\$a1<\$b1) ? $order : 0- $order;");
    uasort($files_matched, $filesort);
  }
  --$depth;
  return $files_matched;

}

$files = preg_find($archive_people_files,$archive_dir, PREG_FIND_FULLPATH | PREG_FIND_RECURSIVE | PREG_FIND_RETURNASSOC | PREG_FIND_SORTMODIFIED | PREG_FIND_SORTBASENAME);

$files=array_keys($files);

/*
// Output each opened file and then close
foreach ($files as $filename) {
         echo "<p>" . $filename;
}
 */

if (!($fp = fopen($output_file_name, 'w'))) {
   return;
}

foreach ($files as $filename) {

 preg_match('/Profiles.(.*).Archive.Messages.(.*).20......-/',$filename, $matches);   
 $account = $matches[1];
 $to = $matches[1];
 $contact = $matches[2];

 $p = 0; // Position in the file's data.
 $data = file_get_contents("${filename}");

 fprintf($fp,"*** $filename\n\n");

 while ($p < strlen($data)) {
     $result = array();

     $pieces = unpack('ltime/lunknown/ltoFrom/llength', substr($data, $p, $p + 16));

     $p += 16;

     $result['date'] = date('r', $pieces['time']);
     $result['to'] = $pieces['toFrom'] ? $contact : $account;

     if ($result['to'] == $from_name) {$result['to'] = $to_name;}

     $cypherText = substr($data, $p, $pieces['length']);

     $p += $pieces['length'];

     // Generates the XOR key by repeating the account name
     // then chopping off extra characters so the entire message
     // can be XOR in one operation.
     $key = str_repeat($to, ceil($pieces['length'] / strlen($to)));
     $key = substr($key, 0, strlen($cypherText));
     $result['text'] = $key ^ $cypherText;

     // There seems to be an extra 4 bytes of junk here.
     $p+=4;

     // Nov 01, 2008 12:34 PersonTalking: That's what SHE said.
     $new_text = preg_replace('/<font.*?Arial">/', '', $result['text'] );
     $new_text = preg_replace('/...000000m/', '', $new_text );
     $new_text = preg_replace('/<.font><.font>/', '', $new_text );
     $new_text = preg_replace('/%/', '%%', $new_text );
     $new_text = preg_replace('/\r/', "\n                               \t                   \t", $new_text );
     $new_text = preg_replace('/\e\[.?2m/', "---- ", $new_text );
//     echo "{$result['date']} {$result['to']}: {$new_text}\n<p>";
     fprintf($fp, "{$result['date']}\t{$result['to']}:\t{$new_text}\n\n");
     }
}

echo "done";
?>
```